# How to design change display mode from window to full screen borderless windows function at runtime?

Tags: c++, winapi, directx, fullscreen, directx-9

For now, I need change the display mode to full screen borderless windows before executing the program to get the desired result. I want to change the display mode from windowed to full screen borderless window by just pressing Alt + Enter when the program is running . How can I modify the code to make it able to change the display mode at runtime?

SystemClass.cpp

```
void SystemClass::InitializeWindows()
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    DEVMODE dmScreenSettings;

    int screenWidth, screenHeight;
    int posX, posY;


    // Get an external pointer to this object
    ApplicationHandle = this;

    // Get the instance of this application
    m_hinstance = GetModuleHandle( NULL );

    // Give the application a name
    m_applicationName = "Zero DirectX Framework";

    // Setup the windows class with default settings
    wc.style            = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW | CS_OWNDC;
    wc.lpfnWndProc      = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra       = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra       = 0;
    wc.hInstance        = m_hinstance;
    wc.hIcon            = LoadIcon( NULL, IDI_WINLOGO );
    wc.hIconSm          = wc.hIcon;
    wc.hCursor          = LoadCursor( NULL, IDC_ARROW );
    wc.hbrBackground    = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject( BLACK_BRUSH );
    wc.lpszMenuName     = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName    = m_applicationName;
    wc.cbSize           = sizeof( WNDCLASSEX );

    // Register the window class
    RegisterClassEx( &wc );

    // Determine the resolution of the clients desktop screen
    screenWidth  = GetSystemMetrics( SM_CXSCREEN );
    screenHeight = GetSystemMetrics( SM_CYSCREEN );

    // Setup the screen settings depending on whether it is running in full screen or in windowed mode
    if ( FULL_SCREEN )
    {
        // If full screen set the screen to maximum size of the users desktop and 32bit
        memset( &dmScreenSettings, 0, sizeof(dmScreenSettings) );
        dmScreenSettings.dmSize         = sizeof(dmScreenSettings);
        dmScreenSettings.dmPelsWidth    = (unsigned long)screenWidth;
        dmScreenSettings.dmPelsHeight   = (unsigned long)screenHeight;
        dmScreenSettings.dmBitsPerPel   = 32;
        dmScreenSettings.dmFields       = DM_BITSPERPEL | DM_PELSWIDTH | DM_PELSHEIGHT;

        // Change the display settings to full screen
        ChangeDisplaySettings( &dmScreenSettings, CDS_FULLSCREEN );

        // Set the position of the window to the top left corner
        posX = posY = 0;

        // Create the window with the screen settings and get the handle to it
        m_hwnd = CreateWindowEx( WS_EX_APPWINDOW, m_applicationName, m_applicationName, 
        WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_POPUP,
        posX, posY, screenWidth, screenHeight, NULL, NULL, m_hinstance, NULL);

        SetMenu( m_hwnd, NULL );
    }
    else
    {
        // If windowed then set it to 800x600 resolution
        screenWidth  = 1280;
        screenHeight = 768;

        // Place the window in the middle of the screen
        posX = ( GetSystemMetrics( SM_CXSCREEN ) - screenWidth ) / 2;
        posY = ( GetSystemMetrics( SM_CYSCREEN ) - screenHeight) / 2;

        m_hwnd = CreateWindowEx( 0, m_applicationName, m_applicationName, WS_CAPTION | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_SYSMENU, 
        posX, posY, screenWidth, screenHeight, 
        NULL, NULL, m_hinstance, NULL );
    }

    // Bring the window up on the screen and set it as main focus
    ShowWindow( m_hwnd, SW_SHOW );
    SetForegroundWindow( m_hwnd );
    SetFocus( m_hwnd );

    // Hide the mouse cursor
    ShowCursor(true);
}
```

Comment: It's covered in just about any DirectX tutorial, just google "DirectX full screen toggle".  First hit looks good.

Comment: What Direct3D version?

Answer (score 0):

You have to [reset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) the device when changing from windowed to full screen and vice versa.
Some notes:

- You must free all memory from the default pool (that is unmanaged video ram) before resetting and realloc thereafter.
- I maintain two different [present parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172588%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for windowed and full screen as the capabilities may differ.
- Note that Reset and CreateDevice change the present parameters you used, e.g. by setting the back buffer size in windowed mode. You may want to make a copy of your original parameters for use in later Reset calls.
- Resetting to windowed mode does not preserve the original window size and position; you have to store them separately.